# cdi not working when using maven filters

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, jboss, cdi

I'm trying to add maven filtering to a project i'm working on, but after I build the project with filtering on, all of the injected beans are `null`. Here is the addition to the pom:

```
<build>
        ...
        <filters>
            <filter>${basedir}/build.properties</filter>
        </filters>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>${basedir}/misc/jboss</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <targetPath>${basedir}/filtered</targetPath>
                <includes>
                    <include>manager.properties</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>${basedir}/misc/jboss</directory>
                <filtering>false</filtering>
                <targetPath>${basedir}/filtered</targetPath>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>*.jar</exclude>
                    <exclude>*.keystore</exclude>
                    <exclude>*.xml</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        ...
</build>
```

I notice that the beans.xml file is missing from the .war file.
I don't understand why the beans.xml is missing, since I'm only applying the filering on a specific directory `<directory>${basedir}/misc/jboss</directory>`...

When I remove the above from the pom everything is working again.
Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean all of the injected beans are null? Is this a spring project?

Comment: No, this is not a spring project. I'm using JEE6 `@Inject`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was indeed related to the `<exclude>*.xml</exclude>` as suggested by @cowls.

But the root cause was due to the fact that when there's at least one `<resource>` element then the default filtering behavior doesn't apply anymore. 
The default filtering behavior is to includer resources under *src/main/resources* in the build, without filtering. So without that default behavior, the **beans.xml** which was under *src/main/resources* wasn't included in the build, thus CDI stopped working.

In order to fix this issue, a 'default' resource had to be included:

```
<resource>
    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
</resource>
```

More information can be found [here](http://piotrnowicki.com/2012/10/filtered-resources-in-maven/).

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're excluding all *.xml files from the build:

```
<exclude>*.xml</exclude>
```

Which is probably causing the problem.

I suspect you either want to remove the exclusions, or add corresponding include elements to the section with filtering set to true.

You probably also want to add a corresponding exclusion for

```
<include>manager.properties</include>
```

Comment: I have tried to change my exlusions to something more specific:   `<exclude>mysql-connector-java-5.1.21-bin.jar</exclude>`  <exclude>idp.keystore</exclude>`  `<exclude>standalone-full.xml</exclude>`  `<exclude>idp-ds.xml</exclude>`.  That's still not fixing the problem. And why should I also add an exclusion for the `<include>manager.properties</include>`?

Comment: Just to be sure it doesnt copy over a non "filtered" version of the file. Whats standalone-full.xml? Is it required by the application?

Comment: standalone-full is the JBoss configuration file, but for now I am copying it manually, so I want it to be excluded from the filtering.

Comment: Found the root cause. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!